# How do I make an Electron login system using mysql or should i do something else?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, authentication, electron

I'm making my first Electron app and I'm not sure whether or not I should use the MySQL npm package or whether I should just use a MySQL in standard JavaScript that loads when the application starts for a login page if you could give me any advice on which to use and how to do it, it would help a lot

**Edit:**
The kind of thing I'm making is an application where there is admins and standard users both using the same login interface and to login they will connect to an online mysql database where it will check if there login details are correct and if they are then it will either give them the standard or admin view in the application and I'm not sure whether or not I should use mysql in javascript or whether or not I should use the npm mysql package and if I should use that instead of using standard javascript?

Also i would like the application to be able to run offline where the user can login online and make edits to things in the app such as their username or password etc (things that would be stored in the database) and have it so when connection is re-established it allows the information in the database to be updated.

I'm simply looking for some advice on how i could do that or some pointers in the right direction like some documentation or some up to date tutorials which might be able to help me and I am new to node/electron and therefore please be patient :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a remote mysql server and used the mysql node package to do this which is very easy to use

`npm install mysql --save`

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Comment: WARNING: This is highly insecure. You are directly connecting client(not in your control) with your database. Don't do this unless the clients are highly trustworthy and you can secure the credentials of your database on client machine or during the network requests. Database requests should be made over backchannel, create APIs to access the backchannel securely(with proper auth strategy).

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr; Checkout [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb)

To interact with mysql database server, you will need it installed and running.

**Ask yourself**

Does user has mysql installed and server running?

How do you handle the users who do not have mysql server installed? Are you going to ask them to download it?

Do I really want to use this mysql or can my functionalities work with some other lightweight database?

For most cases, requirements are simpler and you will not need database such as mysql, I recommend to use lightweight databases such as [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb)

For some really simple applications, I don't even use nedb, rather I simply write and read from a file but you seem to be past that simple situation.

Comment: the kind of thing I'm making is an application where there is admins and standard users both using the same login interface and to login they will connect to an online mysql database where it will check if there login details are correct and if they are then it will either give them the standard or admin view in the application and I'm not sure whether or not I should use mysql in javascript or whether or not I should use the npm mysql package and if i should use that instead of using standard javascript how would I do that?

Comment: Connecting with a remote mysql server directly from client is **not advised** due to security concerns. Alternative: create REST APIs around the database and make http request to those APIs from your electron apps. To learn more google "API with express" or "GraphQL"

Comment: To run offline, as suggested in my answer use database such as nedb to store data locally. Keep syncing the local data with remote server whenever you are online.

Comment: This totally depends on how you want your application to run. If you want to run the application offline you can consider SQLite.
If you want it to run online, Mysql is fine. You will also need a mechanism to sync data from local to online db.

Comment: Sorry if I'm sounding stupid but what do you mean about the API with express as I'm wanting to make the application with Electron and tbh i don't fully understand how to program in NodeJS and thank u for helping

Comment: I see. In that case, first learn about "Client Server Architecture". Then learn about to REST API and how to create one with any language of your choice. 

And for this issue, use the mysql npm package to connect with your mysql server directly. But do not use this product in production(do not use it for real users), use it as learning opportunity(learning about connecting with mysql remotely from a client)

Comment: I think my main issue with it is a mental block for NodeJS because I've tried learning how to use it in the past but I just can't seem to get my head around how it works because i understand the concept of client/server architecture from using PHP in the past where the html is the Frontend which has elements of PHP which is the Backend processed by the server allowing interaction with the Database to prevent the user from having direct access where the tables or data could be edited or damaged but I want to now create a desktop app using this  but with node and electron but have no idea how

Comment: Take one step at a time. If you're comfortable with php, create API in php and learn about javascript by making this electron app. You'll need significant time to learn about javascript and then nodejs, plan for that. 
As we're going beyond the scope of this question, I request you to accept my answer and upvote it. For any other advice, feel free to engage on https://chat.stackoverflow.com